# Non static members in Singleton class

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, static, singleton

I´m doing a singleton class as follows.

```
public class SingletonTest {

    private static SingletonTest instance;

    private Integer result;

    private SingletonTest() {   
    }

    public synchronized static SingletonTest getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new SingletonTest();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Integer calculateResult(int value1, int value2) {
        result = value1 + value2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

But a problem occurs when I call non-static members from multiple threads (with JMeter).

By example:

Thread 1:
SingletonTest.getInstance().calculateResult(1,2) -> return 3

Thread 2:
SingletonTest.getInstance().calculateResult(3,2) -> return 3

I think this happen because 2 threads are accessing in the same time at method and override de property called result.

Comment: Well yes - you've got a race condition. That has nothing to do with it being a singleton, and everything to do with mutating shared state unsafely. You'll need synchronization, or use of something like `AtomicInteger`. What's the actual *question* here?

Comment: yes, this is how a "singleton" works.  you have a single instance with shared state.

Comment: This is very well possible - you have to apply a lock mechanism to prevent race conditions.

Comment: The instance variable isn't even needed.  The `calculateResult` method can return a local variable.  Then synchronization isn't needed.

Comment: @fge - the initialization is thread safe since getInstance is synchronized.

Comment: @jtahlborn Oops, didn't see

Comment: The instance variable is only to simplify a complex process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the second thread is accesing the value of result set by the first thread.

If you are modifying a value that is visible to multiple threads, you should synchronize the operation.

```
public synchronized Integer calculateResult(int value1, int value2) {
    result = value1 + value2;
    return result;
}
```

This way the first thread to call the method gets a lock on the singleton, and the second thread can't access it until its finished.

You should probably review the [official tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) if you are going to use concurrency, especially [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html).

Comment: I have readed, that synchronization is very expensive performance-wise (synchronized methods can run up to 100 times slower than unsynchronized methods). How can I do performance enhancement ?

Comment: @Hector try using [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: The instance variable and the return type is only an example to simplify the problem. The object returned in my project is really a HashMap.

Comment: @Hector [ConcurrentHashMap?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: Thanks Roberto, I didn't know that class.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct and its happening because your shared result instance variable is not thread safe.
Not sure why are you sharing it. Fix code is here:

```
public class SingletonTest {

    private static SingletonTest instance;

    private SingletonTest() {   
    }

    public synchronized static SingletonTest getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new SingletonTest();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Integer calculateResult(int value1, int value2) {
        Integer result = value1 + value2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The instance variable and the return type is only an example to simplify the problem. The object returned in my project is really a HashMap.

Comment: Ok fair enough but it will helpful if you put real data structure in your question because making them thread safe might be different for different data structure based on operation. If you use ConcurrentHashMap and its CAS operation (putifabsent) you can get your expected result instead of using HashMap. I can modify my code if you let me know what you are using as key. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
         return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to google implement singleton in C#, and your answer doesn't address the OPs problem anyway.